# Multiple condition WHERE clause returning unnecessary rows

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

In the stored procedure below, I'm wanting to return rows that do not have `DEL` in the `Flag` column. When I get the result back, the `DEL` rows are included. What am I doing wrong in my `WHERE` clause(I'm assuming that's what it is)?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAllMessages]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Key varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT message.msg_id,
       message.tenant_id,
       message.sender_id,
       message.recipient_id,
       message.recipient_email,
       message.description,
       message.date_recorded,
       message.filename,
       message.size_bytes,
       message.size_time,
       message.filepath,
       message.Flag,
       message.title,
       message.date_activity,
       member.member_image_url
FROM   message
INNER JOIN member
ON message.sender_id = member.person_id
WHERE sender_id = (SELECT person_id FROM auth_key WHERE key = @Key)
OR recipient_id = (SELECT person_id FROM auth_key WHERE key = @Key)
AND Flag != 'DEL'
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect you need some extra parens to segment the logic in the manner you want:

```
WHERE (sender_id = (SELECT person_id FROM auth_key WHERE key = @Key)
OR recipient_id = (SELECT person_id FROM auth_key WHERE key = @Key))
AND Flag != 'DEL'
```